# Measuring AC output of variac with DC voltmeter

Tags: dc, voltmeter

I have variac (Uin=230V, Uout=0-250V, Imax=5A), where I would like to measure voltage on output on a digital voltmeter.
Since I have problems finding digital AC voltmeter 0-300VAC (most of them measure only from ~70V up, but I would prefer form 0V up), I was thinking of measuring voltage with DC voltmeter (these are easy to find to measure 0-300VDC with external power supply of 5-12VDC).
What I would like to do is this: 
[image]

Gretz is used because of DC voltmeter, where I used cap. to smooth the halfperiods into something more likely DC voltage, while resistor is there to discharge (and for faster changes).
Voltage divider is there to divide the voltage, for when it's 324V (230V*1.41) to show on DC voltmeter 230V DC.

Is this a correct way to solve the problem?

Comment: your circuit is plausable .You are measuring the peak which is OK .I would go for the average and calibrate it for RMS which is rough enough .

Comment: What is Gretz???

Comment: @LeonHeller: ["Graetz" is another name for a full wave bridge rectifier.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_bridge)  "Graetz" from the name of the [German guy that invented it.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Graetz)

Comment: Most digital multimeters have high voltage AC ranges that measure from 0 to Vmax VAC. What meters are you using that do not measure below 70 VAC?

Comment: Arguably, the 100k resistor to the left of the capacitor is unnecessary.  The voltage divider to the right of the capacitor also acts a bleed resistor to discharge the capacitor.  Other than that, it's pretty much the way I would do it.  Be aware that, for very low voltages, the volt drop across the diodes will affect the result.

Comment: Simon B, sure. I am well aware of the low voltage, but I'm not really interested in, for instance, 5VAC to be measured very precisely. I would like to adjust voltage by observing the device, then read it from the voltmeter and write it down. Then this is it, shall do it this way. Thank you very much.

@RussellMcMahon: Most of digital ones, because they use only 2 lines to measure (which they use to power aswell). If I would find a digital voltmeter that goes from 0 to 300VAC and has separate power supply, I would prefer that.

Comment: In addition to the 100k resistor, DPST switch is unnecessary.  A SPST is fine, but that appears to be a part of the module.  Circuit looks good, math makes sense.

Comment: DPST is just what I have on stack. I buy those rocker switches in bulk and once I bought SPST and once DPST. In this case would rather use double pole aswell, because you never know which one is the Line and just wanna be sure it's switch on it this time (as you can have on output the 220V and 230V which will represent as 10V).

Comment: Jakey - As you say, meter modules that use 2 wires and power from the measurement leads do have a Vmin rating. BUT digital test meters with multiple ranges and battery power will measure voltage across the whole range. This will allow direct measurement of variac output with none of the added circuitry.

Comment: I want to set a meter on the cases front panel.